# Undefined when trying to get data from form

Tags: node.js, undefined

Same code works fine with other application but for some reason won't work in this one

HTML:

```html
<form action="/employees/add" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
    <input name="first_name" type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name" value="first_name"placeholder="Please enter your first name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
    <input name="last_name" type="text" class="form-control" id="last_name" value="last_name" placeholder="Please enter your last name">
  </div>
</form>
```

Server.js

```js
app.post('/employees/add', (req, res) => {
data.addEmployee(req.body).then(() =>{
  console.log(req.body);
 
  res.redirect('/employees')
});
```

Output:

```
Server running 8080
undefined
```

Of course, when I call addEmployee since req.body is undefined it won't do anything

I tried different app.use(express.static... ) but no luck and here how my folder looks like

[image]

Comment: Why do you use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` if you are sending simple values? You could simply omit it (the default is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded") and then use the `express.urlencoded` middleware in your server.

Comment: yeah i removed it as well. I was originally getting image file as well